# Apollo `useMutation()` stuck loading inside Next.js component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo-client, keystonejs

The following form component in Next.js submits without errors but never completes the mutation. Instead it get's stuck in the `loading` state.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { gql, useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  ssrMode: true,
  uri: process.env.API_URL,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

const CREATE_COMMENT = gql`
  mutation CreateComment(
    $username: String!
    $comment: String!
  ) {
    createComment(
      data: { username: $username, comment: $comment }
    ) {
      id
      username
      comment
    }
  }
`;

export default function SocialForm() {
  const [commentName, updateCommentName] = useState("");
  const [commentDescription, updateCommentDescription] = useState("");
  const [createComment, { data, error, loading }] = useMutation(
    CREATE_COMMENT,
    { client }
  );

  const handleFormSubmit = async () => {
    await createComment({
      variables: {
        name: commentName,
        comment: commentDescription
      },
    });
  };

  if (loading) return "loading...";
  if (error) return <p>error text :(</p>;
  return (
    <>
      <form
        onSubmit={async (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          await handleFormSubmit();
        }}
        className="social-form"
      >
        <input
          required
          onChange={(e) => updateCommentName(e.target.value)}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Full Name"
          className=""
        />
        <textarea
          required
          maxLength="280"
          onChange={(e) => updateCommentDescription(e.target.value)}
          className="w-full"
          name="comment"
          rows="5"
          placeholder="Leave your thoughts and images at the moment"
        />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Also the server side mutation with this exact same schema runs correctly inside Apollo playground and I'm using Keystone.js to auto generate the schema.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your example:

```js
const handleFormSubmit = async () => {
  await createComment({
    variables: {
      name: commentName,   // <-- Shouldn't this be `username: commentName,`?
      comment: commentDescription
    },
  });
};
```

Otherwise, when you say the form "submits without errors but never completes", I assume you mean, from your browser? Can you see the GraphQL request being made in the browsers developer tools? I don't know which one you're in but there should be a way to see the requests being made and their responses. If the GraphQL server is returning an error, you'll see it there.

Also, what is Keystone logging on the command line during all this? If you add some `console.log()` statements to your custom mutation, do they get called?